# Error Undefined Offset in PHP 5.5.6

Tags: php, arrays, function, undefined, offset

I have web application and i use XAMPP ver 1.8.3 with PHP Version 5.5.6
My web application get this error :

```
http://localhost/websekolah/admin/<br /><b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'uid' in <b>C:/xampp/htdocs/websekolah/config/function.php</b> on line <b>25</b><br />main.php?module=buku_tamu&menu=update&$key=1
```

And the error refer to my function.php file.

**function.php**

```
<?php
    function info($message) {
        echo "
            <script>
                alert('$message');
            </script>
        ";  
    }

    function redirect($url) {
        echo("<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=$url'>");
    }

    function url($link, $type, $data) {
        $url = "main.php?module=" . $_GET['module'] . "&$type=$link";

        if($data != NULL) {
            foreach($data as $key => $value) {
                $valKey = $value[$key];
                $url .= '&$key=' . $valKey;
            }   
        }

        return $url;
    }
?>
```

And i call that function like this :

```
<a href="<?php echo url('update','menu', array('uid' => $data['uid'])); ?>" class="table-icon edit" title="Edit"></a>
```

I passing array in my function, and i generated url string.

But in XAMPP 1.7.4 with PHP version 5.3.5, it works.

Any solutions?

Thanks before..

Comment: Can you show the content of $data?

Comment: `$valKey = $value[$key];` Surely either `$valKey = $data[$key];` or `$valKey = $value;`..... but I can't see how it could ever have worked on any version of PHP